# Data from HTML form not reaching MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Halo Developers.

Please help me get my HTML data to the database.

It's connecting and echoing the values correctly, but when I check the database, empty!

Here's the code:

```
<?php

include "conn.php";

    $nyamaV = $_POST['nyamaH']. "<br />";
    $mbogaV = $_POST['mbogaH'];
    $ugaliV = $_POST['ugaliH'];
    $mturaV = $_POST['mturaH'];
    $pizzaV = $_POST['pizzaH'];
    $matumboV = $_POST['matumboH'];
    $omenaV = $_POST['omenaH'];
    $nyanyaV = $_POST['nyanyaH'];
    $kitunguV = $_POST['kitunguH'];
    $daniaV = $_POST['daniaH'];
    $hohoV = $_POST['hohoH'];


$ingizaV = "INSERT INTO scripture (nyamaT, mbogaT, ugaliT, mturaT, pizzaT, matumboT, omenaT, nyanyaT, kitunguT, daniaT, hohoT)
VALUES ('$nyamaV', '$mbogaV', '$ugaliV', '$mturaV', '$pizzaV', '$matumboV', '$omenaV', '$nyanyaV', '$kitunguV', '$daniaV', '$hohoV')";

echo $nyamaV;
echo $mbogaV;
echo $ugaliV;
echo $mturaV;
echo $pizzaV;
echo $matumboV;
echo $omenaV;
echo $nyanyaV;
echo $kitunguV;
echo $daniaV;
echo $hohoV;

?>
```

Comment: Declaring a variable with a query is not the same as running a query.

Comment: Please learn to use prepared statements instead of substituting variables directly into a query. Your code (when you fix it) is subject to SQL injection.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?s=1|1025.2214

Comment: @FirstOne Thanks. I did not know that.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. I will check out the prepared statements. What kind of changes do you recommend on the code?

Comment: @BiasharaEmployers You need to execute the query, using whatever MySQL API you've chosen to use. The answers show how to do it using `mysqli`, you can also use `PDO` instead.

Answer (score -1):

The data will not be saved to the database until you are not executing the query with the help of mysqli_query() method.

For example,

```
$sql_query = "INSERT INTO users(firstname,lastname) VALUES('Lee','Jhonson')";
//$conn = connection parameters that are already defined in your conn.php file
$executed_query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_query );
```

Comment: OP never specified mysqli as API

Answer (score -1):

```
mysqli_query(connection,query);
```

put mysqli connect in connection & put insert query in query

```
mysqli_query($connection,$ingizaV);
//$connection = connection parameters that are already defined in your conn.php file
```

Comment: What if the OP is using PDO?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very helpful.